# Nodejs Require class with initializers

Tags: javascript, class, node.js

For example I have the following class

```
var Person = function(name)
{
  this.sayHi = function()
  {
    return "Hello, " + name + "!";
  }
}

exports.Person = Person;
```

In nodejs I have tried

```
var Person = require('modulename').Person('Will');
```

but this just gave unidentified. How do I require a class with initializers in nodejs??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var mod = require('modulename');
var somePerson = new mod.Person('Will');
```

In you code you called the constructor directly without `new`, so `this` was bound to the global context instead of a new `Person` object. And since you did not return `this` in your function you got the undefined error.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/UCvC2/ for a little demo.

Comment: your calling `Person` instead of `mod.Person`

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix, although slightly awcward looking, I wanted the import on one line as import the class only too create one instance of it looked bad. I guess it wasn't being interpreted as a function. @ThiefMaster thanks about 'new', I forgot about that as well :/

```
var will = new (require('modulename').Person)('Will')
```

Comment: You might want to edit that into your answer. Right now with the missing new it's still incorrect.